# What is the value of adding a GuidAttribute to a class?

Tags: c#

What is the value of adding a GUID to C# class? Look at the example using this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.guidattribute(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: It's for interop scenarios.  You'll know when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

GUIDs are used by COM to identify classes, if you need to access your class using CoCreateInstance it needs a GUID.

If you don't need to expose the class to COM you don't need a GUID

There may also be other interop scenarios I don't know about